# xargs sh -c 'ssh ...' stopping execution when any connection times out

Tags: shell, ssh, xargs

I wrote a little one liner in bash to spit out versions of openssl on my servers ([checking if I'm protected against this most recent openssl vulnerability](https://www.openssl.org/news/secadv_20150709.txt)), but if SSH can't connect and times out, it stops the rest of the script from executing.. I know enough bash to get around, but I'm not quite sure what needs to be done here to force it to continue, maybe trapping SIGTERM and continuing from where I left off? I'm sure there's an easier way..

Here's the command:

```
cat servers.txt | \
  xargs -I {} sh -c "echo {} && ssh -o ConnectTimeout=3 myusername@{} openssl version"
```

Where `servers.txt` is just a big list of IP addresses, one per line

Comment: @CharlesDuffy didn't know that about xargs, thanks!

Comment: You should **never** expand `{}` directly into a `sh -c` or similar script. It isn't safe. You should instead pass `{}` as an argument to the shell and use the appropriate positional arguments in the shell script. The man page for `xargs` indicates that it should only stop the entire execution chain if the inner process exits with an exit code of `255`. I wouldn't expect `ssh` to do that but maybe it does here. Does simply adding `|| exit 1` to the script "fix" the problem?

Comment: (on a different point, `sh` is POSIX sh, not bash -- even if /bin/sh is a link to /bin/bash, it turns off a bunch of features when run that way; just `sh` or `shell` is the appropriate tag when not *explicitly* using bash).

Comment: ...btw, trapping SIGTERM wouldn't help because the decision to stop is *inside xargs*, and xargs is not a part of the shell -- it's a completely external command, so no signal handler inside the shell will change its behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `xargs` man page:

> The xargs utility exits immediately (without processing any further
>   input) if a command line cannot be assembled, utility cannot be invoked,
>   an invocation of utility is terminated by a signal, or an invocation of
>   utility exits with a value of 255.

Presumably your failure is exiting with a status of 255.

---

Personally, I wouldn't bother with `xargs` for this; you aren't doing anything (like parallelization, or putting multiple hostnames on a command line) it's particularly good for.

```
while read -r name <&3; do
  echo "$name"; ssh -o ConnectTimeout=3 username@"$name" "openssl version" ||:
done 3<servers.txt
```

This uses file descriptor 3 for reading the `servers.txt` file so stdin is left at its default value.

---

By the way, if I were writing your code to use xargs, I'd do it like so:

```
xargs sh -c 'for host; do ssh -o ConnectTimeout=3 myusername@"$host" "openssl version" </dev/null' _ <servers.txt
```

That way you're having xargs pass a *list of hosts* to each shell invocation, rather than one shell per host.

Comment: I would have changed the loop to `for name in $(<servers.txt); do ... done`, considering that the file contains just the white-space separated list (otherwise xargs would have failed badly). The reason for this preference: the command being run under ssh can potentially swallow up your stdin from servers.txt.

Comment: @anishsane, that's a legitimate bug, but teaching people to violate http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor is something I'm wary of -- too often someone will remember an idiom without its caveats. Better to redirect stdin from /dev/null explicitly, or put the loop on a FD other than stdin.

Comment: That's how I'm doing it now, yes. Actually tempted to go back and move the input FD number elsewhere (#3?).

Answer (score 1):

Use GNU Parallel which is made for this kind of job:

```
parallel -j0 --retries 3 --slf servers --nonall --timeout 1000% --tag openssl version
```

You will need to prepend 'myusername@' to the lines in 'servers' or use 'User myusername' in ~/.ssh/config.

Answer (score -1):

basically you need NOHUP

"nohup command-name &"  or

"nohup /path/to/command-name arg1 arg2 &"

You are also serialize to the servers.txt, and I would think you might like
to run a foreach() on the content, running each in background.

HOWEVER that creates a secondary issue of how to get your results?
(hint: append to a fixed named results.log)

Comment: The problem isn't the SSH connection that xargs is being run in exiting, it's the SSH connections being created by xargs exiting.